# Trouble understanding modulus on a negative in 'Conways Game of Life'

Tags: python-3.x, modulus

I'm going over the book 'automate the boring stuff with python' and cannot understanding a simple expression with the `%` operator. The expression is `leftCoord  = (x - 1) % WIDTH` which on the first iteration of the loop evaluates to `(0 - 1) % 60`. In my mind the `%` operator should evaluate to the remainder of a division. Why does it evaluate to 9?

This is the part of the program that precedes the expression in question:

```
import random,time,copy

WIDTH = 60
HEIGHT = 20

# Create a list of list for the cells:
nextCells = []
for x in range(WIDTH):
    column = [] # Create a new column.
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            column.append('#') # Add a living cell.
        else:
            column.append(' ') # Add a dead cell.
    nextCells.append(column) # nextCells is a list of column lists.

while True: # Main program loop.
    print('\n\n\n\n\n') # Separate each step with newlines.
    currentCells = copy.deepcopy(nextCells)

    # Print currentCells on the screen:
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            print(currentCells[x][y], end='') # Print the # or space.
        print() # Print a newline at the end of the row.


    # Calculate the next step's cells based on current step's cells:
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            # Get neighboring coordinates:
            # % WIDTH ensures leftCoord is always between 0 and WIDTH -1
            leftCoord  = (x - 1) % WIDTH
            rightCoord = (x + 1) % WIDTH
            aboveCoord = (y - 1) % HEIGHT
            belowCoord = (y + 1) % HEIGHT
```

Comment: This needs more context. It is not an entire statement, so hopefully you pulled it out of a longer expression.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of example, let's assume that you're using a table of 10x10.

The % operator isn't so intuitive when the first number is smaller than the second.  Try going into the interactive python shell and running 4 % 10.  Try 8 % 10.  Notice how you always get the same number back?  That's because the answer to the division is 0... with your whole number being left over as remainder.  For most numbers in the table, the modulus doesn't do anything at all.

Now try -1 % 10 (simulating what this would do for the top row).  It gives you 9, indicating the bottom row.  If you run 10 % 10 (simulating the bottom row), it gives you 0, indicating the top row.  Effectively, this makes the table "wrap"... the cells in the top row affect the bottom and vice versa.  It also wraps around the sides.

Hope this helps!